# return extraneous value left in the std::cin input buffer

Tags: c++, cin

I am new to C++. And I am not sure if this has already been answered. Consider the programs below.

Program 1:

```
# include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int x{};
    std::cin >> x;
    std::cout << x;
}
```

Sample Input:
5a

Output:
5

What's happening here is: 'a' doesnt match with type of variable x. So only 5 is stored in x and 'a' is left in the input buffer for later extraction.

My question is: How can i check if there is any extraneous value in the input buffer (after the successful extraction of 5)? For the previous example, the extraneous value is 'a'.

I want to do something like this:

Program 2:

```
# include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::cout << "\nEnter an integer: ";
    int x{};
    std::cin >> x;

    std::cout << "Extraneous value left in the input buffer is " << returnBufferValue();  // i want this function which returns the extraneous value left in the buffer at a point
}
```

Sample Output:

Enter an integer: 5a

Extraneous value left in the input buffer is a

I know I can extract the value left in the input buffer by using another std::cin function right after the 6th line of Program 1. Like say,

```
auto y{};  // Line 7
std::cin >> y;  // Line 8
```

But in that case, if the user input is completely valid and doesn't have any extraneous value, then the program will halt and want another input from the user, which is not my purpose. So, is there any solution for what I am trying to do?

I intend to do some task depending on the existence of extraneous value in the input buffer.

Comment: Read a whole line as a string so you can parse the whole thing at once. That's a more natural way to read input IMO.

Comment: Not in standard C++. You cannot read from standard input without also pausing if there is no pending input. You need to rethink how you accept the users input. Read a line at a time and parse the input to see if it is in the form you want. Or (as a beginner) just don't worry too much about input validation. There's more important things for you to be learning about.

Comment: Yeah I thought about parsing. I was just curious if there exists a function like returnBufferValue() which is able to read the input buffer.

Comment: @john : getting into the habit of input validation early is better than having to unlearn bad habits later. So, I applaud and encourage the op for thinking of this early on. The stakes are too high (the amount of security holes that could have been avoided with rigorous input validation is a testament to that).

Comment: @SuperNoob : [`std::getline`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) is your friend. You can either use it to read the rest of the line from the input stream into a `std::string`, or better yet (as suggested by others), structure your entire input approach around reading line by line into a buffer, then parsing the necessary data out of that buffer (using [`std::stringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) eg.).

Comment: @Sander De Dycker : Thank you for your advice. Gonna do it right now.